# Oat Bran in Sealed Canisters

Tags: customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, australia

I will be travelling to Australia for a couple weeks. Daily intake of oat bran is a routine for me. Am I able to take a couple of manufacturer-sealed canisters of oat bran?

Comment: Why not buy it in Australia?

Comment: @pnuts yeah I wondered about that too, but thought perhaps Shu just didn't realise it was available in Australia.

Comment: @MarkMayo Haha. That heightened debate has lead us to think twice about questioning simple things. But in all fairness, sometimes a person feels more comfortable with what they are used to in comparison to just buying it elsewhere (foreign country syndrome I guess?)

Comment: If there's a preference for a particular brand, it's likely that brand isn't going to be available in Australia.

Answer (score 2):

Austraila is very hot on bio security and as such requires that you declare EVERYTHING food wise.

If you don't you can be fined $au 340

The Australian department of agriculture has a good website with information on it here

http://www.daff.gov.au/biosecurity/travel/cant-take

The thing I noticed was in particular that if you declare your items and they are not allowed all that will happen is the food will be destroyed. But if you hide the food the come down like a ton of bricks.

So take the bran with you, and declare it on arrival. At worse they willthrow it away.

If you have a favourite brand, and some oat brans are coarser than others, then you might want to have tour of austrailan supermarkets websites.

Coles, Woolworths, Safeway, and others

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_supermarket_chains_in_Oceania

Enjoy your trip

Comment: Actually you no longer need to declare everything food-wise.  They relaxed it a few years ago, so only it fits into some broad categories, e.g. unprocessed foods, honeys, dairy, etc.  However if you want to be sure you're still better declaring it than not, simply because the categories can be quite vague.

Comment: dlanod is correct - [source](http://www.news.com.au/travel/airport-joy-on-the-way-for-weary-aussies/story-e6frfq7r-1226515688697)

Answer (score 1):

If it's pre-packaged food, you're generally able to get it in.  If you need it you're better off playing it safe and declaring it but I haven't seen them confiscate pre-packaged food coming in from a country with reputable food standards.

Comment: Huh, every single time I have tried to take some food product -- I mean completely packaged/sealed (in a tin or sealed plastic packaging) in to Sydney ........ it has been confiscated. (I mean, bringing gifts for friends.) I DON'T KNOW if "oats" is, in particular, is on some list.  But Aussie customs-checking-for-food is generally regarded as incredibly strict.  (And wait until you see the taxi "system" at the airport! :O )

Comment: I've brought through food at least a dozen times and have never had it confiscated.  They may apply different levels of strictness for different nationalities (Australian here), but as I alluded to in my answer I suspect it may vary by initiating countries.  We've brought our's in from SA, North America, NZ, Singapore, Vietnam and Europe in the last five years, but there's obviously fair swathes of the globe unaccounted for.

Comment: [source](http://www.news.com.au/travel/airport-joy-on-the-way-for-weary-aussies/story-e6frfq7r-1226515688697)